# How to make popup video responsive respective to mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, magento

```
<button type="button" class="action-oser" id="click-vlink2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-3 18v-12l10 6-10 6z" style="fill:#fff" /></svg>
</button>
<div id="video-modal2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content-oser">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" id="youtube2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JexOJOssGwk?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apetito.co.uk&widgetid=1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
               
                modalClass: 'nursery-modal',
                'buttons': [{
                    class: 'action-oser'
              }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#video-modal2'));
            $("#click-vlink2").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#video-modal2").modal("openModal");
            });
            $('.action-close').on('click', function() {
            var video = $("#youtube2").attr("src");
            $("#youtube2").attr("src","");
            $("#youtube2").attr("src",video);
            });
            


        }
    );
</script>
```

I added above script for modal popup video. i added this width="560" height="315" in iframe and it is required size for desktop. But when i'm checking in the mobile devices its not fit according to the mobile device.

How can i make this responsive to the all mobile devices also.

Any help can be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a [`style=""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) attribute in the `<iframe>`

with this css code `max-width: 100%;`

[image]

> this means that the video iframe in mobile always takes less than the width of the device.
>
>  
>  and also the height remain the same, so the content below can be visible.

```html
<iframe style="max-width: 100%;" width="560" height="315" id="youtube2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JexOJOssGwk?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apetito.co.uk&widgetid=1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

> **useful documentations:**
>
>  - `max-width`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width
>
>  - `style attribute`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style

Answer (score 0):

i guess this can help you.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   iframe {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: auto !important;
       height: auto !important;
   }
}
```

and for more solution example visit :
https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/how-to-make-a-responsive-100-width-youtube-iframe-embed